# Non uniformly integrable sequence

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, uniform-integrability

I am looking for a sequence of random variable $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ on $([0,1], \mathbb B, \lambda)$ such that
$$X_n\to 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$
$$EX_n\to 0$$
but such that $(X_n)_n$ is *not* uniformly integrable.

I already showed that the sequence can't have $X_n\geq 0$ for all $n$. Can we maybe achieve it with linear combinations of indicator functions $\mathbb 1_{[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $$X_n := n 1_{(0,1/n)}-n 1_{(1/n,2/n)}$$